# How to continue from the break in a for loop

Tags: c#, loops

```
string[] sentence = new string[] { "I like C++.", "I like C#.", "I like Java." };

for (int i = 0; i < sentence.Length; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < sentence.Length; j++)
    {
        richTextBox1.Text += sentence[j] + "\n";
        break;
    }
}
```

Is it possible to continue the inner loop from where it stops so I can get the output of:

```
I like C++.
I like C#.
I like Java.
```

Comment: Why do you think the break is mandatory?

Comment: What is the point of the 2nd loop if you're only doing 1 iteration anyways??

Comment: Why do you have the `break` there? That's effectively saying `richTextBox.Text += sentenct[0] + "\n";` when it hits that loop. You'll only ever get `I\nI\nI\n`

Comment: "Given that the codes do not contain error" - well, they look pretty ropy to me. You're not using `i` anywhere, for example, and the desired result could be achieved *much* more simply...

Comment: Can you please rephrase the question

Comment: To simplify my question, is it possible to continue from where the inner loop stop?

Comment: @Shil. By removing the break, it can be certainly done.But how if the break is there?

Comment: It would seem that you are looking for the literal answer rather than a solution to this code. The answer is no, if you have used `break` then you have used it for a reason

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
richTextBox1.Text = string.Join("\n", sentence );
```

Answer (score 1):

The `break` keyword will always "break-out" of the current block of code. In this case, it is your inner for-loop.

I think you looking for the `continue` keyword.

Comment: its more of a comment than answer

Answer (score 0):

Try simply below:

```
string[] sentence = new string[] { "I like C++.", "I like C#.", "I like Java." };

for (int i = 0; i < sentence.Length; i++)
{
        richTextBox1.Text += sentence[j] + "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] sentence = new string[] { "I like C++.", "I like C#.", "I like Java." };

            for (int i = 0; i < sentence.Length; i++)
            {
                xyz:

                for (int j = i; j < sentence.Length; j++)
                {
                    richTextBox1.Text += sentence[j] + "\n";
                    break;
                }

                 i++;
                 if (i == sentence.Length) { break; }
                 goto xyz;
            }
```

Comment: The for loop in this case does nothing because of the goto... the GoTo needs to be inside of an if statement.

Comment: @Raymond please check it now

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] sentence = new string[] { "I like C++.", "I like C#.", "I like Java." };

for (int i = 0; i < sentence.Length; i++)
{
    for (int j = **i**; j < sentence.Length; j++)
    {
        richTextBox1.Text += sentence[j] + "\n";
        break;
    }
}
```

Instead of int j = 0, make it as int j = i in the second loop.. Though there are better solutions to "THIS" problem, I assume you are looking at a different set of problems to check if such continuation is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you do not want to end of the line after the last item? Then:

```
string[] sentence = new string[] { "I like C++.", "I like C#.", "I like Java." };

for (int i = 0; i < sentence.Length; i++) {
    richTextBox1.Text += sentence[j];
    if(i < sentence.Length-1)
        richTextBox1.Text += "\n";
}
```